# Taking images from webservices gives error

Tags: react-native

I call webservices to take images. Images are coming as ByteArray. When total size of images below 50kb, there is no problem, but when total images is above 50kb webservice gives me an error like this:

```
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

I call webservice like this:

```
fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
        }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then(leaders => {
      console.log('leader: ', leaders);
    });
```

Error is:

[image]

I don't know if it is exactly 50 or not because my Images' size is between 9-10kb. When I call 5 images it doesn't give an error but more than 5 it gives an error like above.

Here is the Network tab:

[image]

Comment: Cant anybody help about this question

Comment: Go to the Network tab and take a look at the returned content. Apparently it's  not json, because it starts with the letter 'a'

Comment: I put network tab screen. What does it mean ? @diogenesgg

Comment: This is obviously a problem in the backend, not in the mobile app.

Comment: I  can call webservice without problem in c#. But why it gives error in react-native @JJJ

Comment: I can't possibly know because you haven't shown the webservice code.

Comment: By the way, I fixed this problem with  'react-native-fetch-polyfill'. this mistake was because of  timeout.

Comment: you may add an answer to your own question and accept it yourself. this will allow this post to be more useful and clear to others